# Where can i declare parameter in Jasper server's mdx query

Tags: jasper-reports, mdx, jasperserver

My Database is postgresql(9.3) and we are using Jasper Server for Reports

We are having an issue is
i.e we want to make this below mdx query into dynamic.

Here we used filter funtion for searching the employees.but this is static
In runtime we have to pass employee ids as values to this query

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[AMOUNT]} ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    (
      [Consititution Structure].[ALL Consititution Structures]
     ,[Account Detail].[ALL Account Details]
     ,[Monthly Calendar].[ALL Monthly Calendars]
    )
  } ON ROWS
FROM [Annu]
WHERE 
  Filter
  (
    [Empidentity].[All Employees].Children
   ,
      Instr
      (
        [Empidentity].[All Employees].CurrentMember.Properties("Caption")
       ,"110"
      )
    > 0
  );
```

For that we have to declare parameter and assign the values to this parameter during runtime.
but the problem we can't made this query into dynamic.because we don't know  where to declare parameter and how to use in jasper olap views

What we did in Jasper Server

1) we have been established datasource connection(postgresql)

2) we refrenced the xml file for Schema Analysis

3) we created client connection

4) we created olap view using mdx query(this mdx query we should make it into dynamic)

Comment: can you use `dynamic-sql` ?

Comment: Please give a sample case and the expected output.